How to split columns of a table in next page using itext7 on .NET Core, if 30 columns in table and print in pdf, first 10 columns will be on 1st page
I am using itext7 and I want to print a .PDF by html and the columns should split in different pages if I have many columns because it is going out of the PDF size.
I have tried many ways but no result. Conversion should be from html to PDF.
